# ERROR: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. Other solutions are not working for me

Tags: c#, sharepoint, foreach

I'm deleteing users in a Sharepoint site and i get this error.
Here's my code:

```
foreach (SPUser user in users) 
{
    string user_name = user.LoginName;

    string[]username = user_name.Split('\\');
    user_name = username[1].ToString().ToLower();


    bool exists= checkIfExists(user_name);
    if (exists != true)
    {

        users.Remove(user.LoginName);
    }
}
```

I've read similar issues but The solutions i found are not working for me since i can't use ToList() or ToArray() method.

Comment: *Why* can't use use `ToList` or `ToArray`? What did you try, and what failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use ToList() or ToArray() directly, create a new list and add items from `users` to it, then use that new list in the `foreach` loop

Though it is obious that your `users` implement `IEnumerable` interface (otherwise you wouldn't be able to use it in the foreach loop), so ToArray() is a preferred way to solve your problem. Maybe you can't use ToArray() because the implementation is not generic? In this case try `users.OfType<SPUser>().ToArray()`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your collection is **really** too big (and then you can't use `ToArray()` or `ToList()`, I can't see any other reason you have to avoid them or through `.Cast<SPUser>().ToArray()` if it doesn't implement `IEnumerable<SPUser>` but only `IEnumerable`) then first create a **collection of items you have to remove**:

```
    var usersToRemove = new List<SPUser>();
    foreach (var user in users) {
        string user_name = user.LoginName;

        string[]username = user_name.Split('\\');
        user_name = username[1].ToString().ToLower();

        if (!checkIfExists(user_name))
            usersToRemove.Add(user.LoginName);
    }
}
```

Now you can iterate `itemsToRemove` collection safely because you enumerate `usersToRemove` but you change users:

```
foreach (var userToRemove in usersToRemove)
    users.Remove(userToRemove);
```

**EDIT** To summarize: if possible convert users to an array (with `users.ToArray()` or with `users.Cast<SPUser>().ToArray()` if it doesn't implement `IEnumerable<SPUser>`):

```
foreach (var user in users.ToArray()) {
```

Or:

```
foreach (var user in users.Cast<SPUser>().ToArray()) {
```

If it's not possible then create an side collection where you'll put items to remove and then you'll iterate through it:

```
var usersToRemove = users
    .Select(x => x.Split('\\')[1].ToLower())
    .Where(x => !checkIfExists(x))
    .ToArray();

foreach var userToRemove in usersToRemove)
    users.Remove(userToRemove);
```